# Ignoring the year in SQL Query with date range

Tags: mysql, sql

Normally if I want to make a query on a table by date range I'll do it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID AS 'id' FROM CUST c 
JOIN TICKET t ON s.ID = t.SALE_ID 
WHERE c.ACTIVE_IND = 1 
AND t.DELIV_DATE BETWEEN '01-01-2012' AND '01-02-2012'
ORDER BY t.DELIV_DATE DESC
```

Now I need to make the same query but ignore the year, so I can say from February 28 to March 2 and year doesn't matter.

I tried modifying the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID AS 'id' FROM CUST c 
JOIN TICKET t ON s.ID = t.SALE_ID 
WHERE c.ACTIVE_IND = 1 
AND MONTH(t.DELIV_DATE) BETWEEN  ... AND ... 
AND DAY(t.DELIV_DATE) ... BETWEEN ...
ORDER BY t.DELIV_DATE DESC
```

Above query works fine if the starting DAY is smaller than the ending. that means if I go from   lets say Feb 20 to Feb 28 it works fine but if I go with Feb 28 to Mar 2 it won't work.

Any solution for this that I can make this happen in a single query ?

Comment: You should use DAYOFYEAR and MAKEDATE and set them all to same year. Say both with be MAKEDATE(1971,DAYOFYEAR(t.DELIV_DATE)) between MAKEDATE(1971,DAYOFYEAR('01-01-2012')) and MAKEDATE(1971,DAYOFYEAR('01-02-2012'))

Comment: Thanks for you comment Sergey. It appears to be fine but deathApril's  solutions seems to be simple and less complicated. however i should run couple of more tests on it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
...
AND DATE_FORMAT(t.DELIV_DATE, '%m%d') BETWEEN '0101' AND '0201'
...
```

---

**Update** - to handle range that loops though the end year (replace `0101` and `0201` with actual variables representing `from` and `to`):

```
...
AND
  (DATE_FORMAT(t.DELIV_DATE, '%m%d') BETWEEN '0101' AND '0201'
   OR '0101' > '0201' AND
     (DATE_FORMAT(t.DELIV_DATE, '%m%d') >= '0101' OR
      DATE_FORMAT(t.DELIV_DATE, '%m%d') <= '0201'
     )
  )
...
```

Comment: nice and simple I like it. @SergeyBenner MySQL has Date_Format

Comment: i don't know if `01-02-2012` from question is January 2nd or February 1st - in my answer it's obviously Ferbruary 1st ;))

Comment: What about if the desired date range loops years?

Comment: how can it loop years if it should be independent of years?!? it would always be true then

Comment: it won't work. i just tested it. `select  DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%d%m') between '0210' and '0310';` returns 0  with any combination without a year.

Comment: @SergeyBenner not much into MySQL myself,, does it work without FROM and WHERE clauses?!? what is the result of `select DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%m%d')`

Comment: @SergeyBenner: deathApril has `'%m%d'` in his answer. You have `'%d%m'`

Comment: @deathApril - Well, the range of dates between April and October is **NOT** the same set of dates as between October and April.  Your statement won't handle conditions where the ending 'date' is before your starting one.

Comment: @X-Zero of course it would handle it - it would return zero rows as expected (if BETWEEN in MySQL is implemented according to the SQL standard)

Comment: @deathApril: What X-Zero means that if one asks for dates between `Dec-25` and `Jan-06`, then it should return some days. Yours will not.

Comment: @X-Zero: Now, it handles it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8326/discussion-between-deathapril-and-ypercube)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($dates[0] != '0000-00-00') {    
                        if(str_replace('-','',substr($dates[0],4))<=str_replace('-','',substr($dates[1],4))){
                        $having[] = '   DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, "%m%d") BETWEEN ? AND ?';                           
                        }else{                              
                        $having[] = '   DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, "%m%d") >= ? OR
                                        DATE_FORMAT(`birthday`, "%m%d") <= ?';
                        }
                        $params[] = str_replace('-','',substr($dates[0],4));
                        $params[] = str_replace('-','',substr($dates[1],4));                                                        
                    }
```

including example when Dates are this same

Answer (score -1):

lets say Feb 28 to May 2 to be more complicated:

```
.... AND ((month(DELIV_DATE)=2 and day(DELIV_DATE)>=28) or (month(DELIV_DATE) between 3 and 4) or (month(DELIV_DATE)=5 and day(DELIV_DATE)<=2)
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something a little more generic.  This also won't work if the date range loops years.

Comment: thanks for your time but to be honest I don't understand the logic behind your solution :D