# Select between date range ignoring the year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have a table that stores opening dates in 2 columns with the type `Date`. I need to select the entries which are open during a date range, but without taking the year in regard.

To prevent confusion I'll write all dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` or `MM-DD`.

Here's a simple example for the table.

```
|  ID   |    Start   |     End    |
|   1   | 2014-12-01 | 2014-12-31 |
|   2   | 2015-11-18 | 2016-01-20 |
|   3   | 2015-01-01 | 2016-01-18 |
|   4   | 2015-12-10 | 2015-12-20 |
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491312/ignoring-the-year-in-sql-query-with-date-range) I'm able to look for entries that are in the same year. This query for example would give me the rows 1 and 4 if I'm looking for anything open between `12-13` and `12-15`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Dates
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(Start, "%m%d") <= DATE_FORMAT("2015-12-13", "%m%d") AND 
    DATE_FORMAT(End, "%m%d") >= DATE_FORMAT("2016-12-15", "%m%d")
```

Looking for entries between `12-01` and `01-13` won't work with this though.

Does anybody have an idea how I'd be able to do this?

**Edit**

Just so everybody interested has the testing table.

```
CREATE TABLE `Dates` (
  `idDates` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `End` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDates`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `Dates`
(`idDates`,
`Start`,
`End`)
VALUES
('1', '2014-12-01', '2014-12-31'),
('2', '2015-11-18', '2016-01-20'),
('3', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-18'),
('4', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-20');
```

Comment: Remember: a "date" is actually a *number*, representing a *point in time*.  It is *not* a "record" containing distinct month, day and year values.  So you can't easily say "give me all records between Dec 15 and Dec 27, regardless of whatever year either date occurs in".

Comment: Are you sure that logic is right? 'start' is less than or equal to 13/12/2015 and 'end' is greater than or equal to 15/12/2015 - both need to be true.

Comment: I think you inverted the operators on your query... try `... >= ... AND ... <= ...`

Comment: You have table with ranges `start/end` (with year) and a single range `start/end` with only month/day?

Comment: Do you want the store be open in the entire range ? What about if open during a part of that range?

Comment: Yes, I'm just looking for entries open during the entire range, that's why the operators are that way.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you have two variables:  `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`.  Then you can write the logic as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Dates
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(@StartDate, '%m%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(@EndDate, '%m%d')  AND
       DATE_FORMAT(Start, '%m%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(@StartDate, '%m%d') AND 
       DATE_FORMAT(End, '%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(@EndDate, '%m%d') 
      ) OR
      (DATE_FORMAT(@StartDate, '%m%d') > DATE_FORMAT(@EndDate, '%m%d')  AND
       DATE_FORMAT(Start, '%m%d') > DATE_FORMAT(@StartDate, '%m%d') AND 
       DATE_FORMAT(End, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(@EndDate, '%m%d') 
      );
```